# use JsonConvert to SerializeObject with varying parameters

Tags: c#, json, ajax, serialization, parameters

I'm returning Json to Ajax to change some html on my page. The c# looks like this:

```
public JsonResult AddToCart(int id, int sizeid, int sizeVal, int catID)
{
    Cake C = db.Cakes.Find(id);


    List<Item> cart = new List<Item>();
    if (Session["cart"] == null)
    {
        cart.Add(new Item(C, 1, sizeid, sizeVal));
        Session["cart"] = cart;
    }

    else
    {
        cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
        int index = isExisting(id, sizeid);
        if (index == -1)
            cart.Add(new Item(C, 1, sizeid, sizeVal));
        else
            cart[index].Quantity++;
        Session["cart"] = cart;
    }



    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cart.Select(b => new { b.Cake.Image, b.Cake.Name, b.SizeVal, b.Quantity,  b.Cake.CakeDetails.Where(c => c.SizeID == b.Size).FirstOrDefault().Price, b.Cake.CakeID, b.Size }),
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

I have two categories of cakes which are cupcakes and cakes. The cakes have a two sizes and two prices for each size whereas the cupcakes don't have a size.

When I run this method on a cake it works perfectly but when I run it on a cupcake it give me this error:

> System.NullReferenceException

That's because the cupcakes don't have a `b.Size` or a `c.SizeID` as written in the code above.

Is there a way I can allow null's in the `cart.Select(b => new { ... })` method?
Or can I put an if statement or something in the `cart.Select(b => new { ... })`

I want to use the same AddToCart method return cakes and cupcakes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured out the correct answer

I made a new method like this:

```
 public double GetPrice(IEnumerable<CakeDetail> CakeD, int? size)
    {
        if (size.HasValue)
        {
            var Check = CakeD.Where(d => d.SizeID == size.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            if (Check != null)
            {
                return Check.Price;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var Check = CakeD.FirstOrDefault();
            if (Check != null)
            {
                return Check.Price;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

and then I wrote this in the AddToCart method's return:

```
   return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cart.Select(b => new {
   Price = GetPrice(b.Cake.CakeDetails, b.Size)
   }),
   Formatting.Indented,
   new JsonSerializerSettings { }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cart.FirstOrDefault(...);
```

instead of `Select()`;

It can return null as well, so perform null-check before continuing.

Comment: If write FirstOrDefault instead of Select I get errors saying: "Cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type: string Image, string Name, int? SizeVal, int Quantity, double Price, int CakeID, int? Size>' to 'bool'"
 and 
"Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"

Answer (score 0):

```
b.Cake.CakeDetails.Where(c => c.SizeID == b.Size).FirstOrDefault()
```

Chances are there to get the above expression's result as `null` and then `.Price` on null will cause the exception you've mentioned.

To avoid this, use `Select(p=> p.Price)` before taking `FirstOrDefault()`.

You should use:

```
return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cart.Select(b => new { b.Cake.Image, b.Cake.Name, b.SizeVal, b.Quantity,  Price = b.Cake.CakeDetails.Where(c => c.SizeID == b.Size).Select(p=> p.Price).FirstOrDefault(), b.Cake.CakeID, b.Size }),
Formatting.Indented,
new JsonSerializerSettings { }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: When i use that I get a red squiggly line under b.Cake.CakeDetails.Where(c => c.SizeID == b.Size).Select(p=> p.Price).FirstOrDefault() and error saying:
Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.